# JSON Serialize HashMap as root element

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a class which is basically a wrapper for a HashMap. I would like to serialize this class with Jackson to an JSON object without any wrapping element.

```
   public class Customers {

        @JsonProperty
        private Map<String,Customer> customers = new HashMap<>();

        ...     

    }
```

Current serialization looks like this:

```
{
   "Customers":{
       "customers":{
          "keyX":{...},
          "keyY":{...},
          "keyZ":{...}
}
```

But I want to have this:

```
{
   "keyX":{...},
   "keyY":{...},
   "keyZ":{...}
}
```

How can I reach it?

Comment: What about doing this manually ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try this

```
jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(customerObj.getCustomers());
```

Simply pass the Map, instead of Customer object.

Comment: Why is this accepted? It would still wrap the key/value pairs of the map with the name of the map "customers" - not answering the original question.

Answer (score 5):

Try @JsonUnwrapped on the property  Customers this can help you unwrap a nested level